# Href link that redirects to another page has a specific action

Tags: javascript, html, href

On my site I created several href buttons, I want these different buttons to lead to the same page but with an additional js action.
As when I click on the first link, this brings me to the page so   and the second leads to the same page but with a javascript action activated.

I hope I have been clear enough and that this is possible, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

adding a class/id to it would help I think. I'm new here so let me know if that's what you are looking for

```
<a class="script" href="...">Link</a>
```

then in your javascript, you can manipulate it

```
var link = document.querySelector(".script");

link.addEventListener("click", function(){

    // your function here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this happen by sending url parameters with each href button: `/page.html?action=1` . See [parsing url parameters in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Next on `page.html` use the following javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let action = url.searchParams.get("action");
    if (action == "1") {
        //perform an action
        action1();
    } else if (action == "2") {
        action2();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I have a page where there are buttons that lead to another page or there are buttons that make things happen in js, and I want that when we click the button on the first page, we arrives on the second page when js is activated.
Basically I explain my site I have a button "visual identity" which should lead to another page (easy), on this second page there is
sub-buttons like "fish" which display a menu with js commands, its sub-buttons are also on the first page and I want when you click on the sub-button on the first page it will take you to the second page with menu opening.
I don't know if that's what you understood just above?
but thanks for your reply.